# Cannot find the path of the specific field in firestore

Tags: android, node.js, google-cloud-firestore

I want to get the token_id and the user's Email of the User logging in the firebase Authentication. the structure of my firestore is like this.

[image: Firebase Database Console]

I am Calling my firestore structure in node.js as,

[image: index.js file]

but I am getting both the fields as undefined in the firebase CLI window.

I cannot determine the correct path to get these 2 fields. i have reached an intermediate level of learning firebase. however, i still face some small problems.

Please help me to achieve this thing. thanks in advance.

[image: Firebase CLI functions]

Comment: Your path is fine. Have you tried to use `const.token_id = change.params.token_id;`?

Comment: its not working even after using the change argument

Comment: I don't understand why you would expect `context.params.token_id` to have a value? Your token_id lives on the documens data? Are you not interested in the documents data, i.e. `change.after.data().token_id`?

Comment: ok i got it..so we have to use the change.after.data().token_id (or any other field). so its the matter of runtime that the token_id is generated spontaneously which the context cannot fetch directly. also, the change argument is used in terms of documents? am i right. please tell me the difference between change and context. i will  be thankful to you.

Comment: You can read more about change vs context on the firebase functions documentation. But change contains the documents (including data) from before and after (if its an update). Context is other related meta info. Hope it helps :)